# Python Pandas Sum on Date and Description

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am using Python 2.7. I have a Pandas data frame that looks like

```
raw_data = {'Date': ['12/1/2016', '12/4/2016','12/23/2016', '1/18/2017','1/18/2017','1/19/2017'], 
    'Account': ['aa1', 'aa2','aa1', 'aa1', 'aa1', 'aa2'], 
    'Description': ['store1', 'store2','store1', 'store2','store1','store2' ], 
    'Amount': [26.43, 24.99, 31.54,45.32, 2.00, 15.41],
    'Category': ['G','G','G','G','G','G'],
    'Initials': ['FR','DB','FR','DB','FR','FR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Date','Account','Description','Amount','Category','Initials'])
```

I would like to sum by each Description and month so that my data looks like:
Date Description Amount 
Dec 2016 store1 57.97 
Dec 2016 store2 24.99 
Jan 2017 store1 2.00 
Jan 2017 store2 60.73

I have written the below code that sums by month but i am stuck on how to incorporate the Description column.

```
#convert Date to datetimeindex
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

#sum by month
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).sum()
df
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert `datetime`s to format `name of month` with `Year` and add column `Description` to `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b %Y'),'Description']).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
       Date Description  Amount
0  Dec 2016      store1   57.97
1  Dec 2016      store2   24.99
2  Jan 2017      store1    2.00
3  Jan 2017      store2   60.73
```

If need `Datetime`s then add only another column `Description`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')

df = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("M"),'Description']).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
        Date Description  Amount
0 2016-12-31      store1   57.97
1 2016-12-31      store2   24.99
2 2017-01-31      store1    2.00
3 2017-01-31      store2   60.73
```

For remove warning in newer version of pandas use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="M"),'Description']).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
        Date Description  Amount
0 2016-12-31      store1   57.97
1 2016-12-31      store2   24.99
2 2017-01-31      store1    2.00
3 2017-01-31      store2   60.73
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `groupby` `dt.month` and `Description`. Use `dt.strftime` and convert the month number to a month name, and *then* perform the grouping:

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.strftime('%b %Y'),
       'Description']).Amount.sum().reset_index()

       Date Description  Amount
0  Dec 2016      store1   57.97
1  Dec 2016      store2   24.99
2  Jan 2017      store1    2.00
3  Jan 2017      store2   60.73
```